# Get the first letter/number of string that is not a special character

Tags: php, preg-match, extract, alphanumeric

I have:

```
$string = ')(8234@#$ABCFG3478&* hello';
```

And I want to get the *first* letter/number in the string that is not a special character. In above string, it should be `8`.

Is there a **non-regex** way to do it, and is that way quicker than below working regex?

```
if (preg_match('/[a-z0-9]/i', $string, $match)) {
    $firstLetter = $match[0];
} else {
    // no match
}

echo $firstLetter;
```

Comment: Does the sting always start with `)(` ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ No, that is an example. I want to target the first letter/number that is **not** a special character. Updated my question.

Comment: Why _non-regex_ way? With regex you could use something like `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")` to get rid off special chars.

Comment: How about [`strcspn()`](https://php.net/strcspn)?

Comment: @Jax-p What's the difference between your regex approach and mine? The reason why I want to avoid is to microoptimize the code.

Comment: @Jax-p - That would remove numbers as well.

Comment: @rid please post an answer with this approach.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, you could just use something like `$string[strcspn($string, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")]`, but it's about the same speed as your approach.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, in conclusion, it's likely that your approach is the best in terms of both performance and maintainability.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, one idea would be to write a PHP extension in C. If you can pass the array of strings to process to the C function instead of calling it in a PHP loop, you can gain even more performance.

Comment: [`ltrim()`](https://php.net/ltrim) and [`strtok()`](https://php.net/strtok) with a string consisting of all non-printable ASCII characters also take about the same time as the original regex.

Answer (score 2):

So this is kinda far fetched right now, but you can do it in a reverse style. I do not recommend to check every character in the string, that would take way too long.

PHP is pretty quick by replacing stuff in strings. That's why you define a list via array, with all "special character elements" that can actually occur in the string, and string replace them with... NOTHING:

```
<?php
$string = ')(8234@#$ABCFG3478&* hello';
$special_character_list = ['(', ')', ]; // Extend the list if you like
$sanitized_string = str_replace($special_character_list, '', string);
```

Edit: Another approach, we create a list of allowed characters, to not define endless lists of not allowed characters.

```
<?php
$string = ')(8234@#$ABCFG3478&* hello';
$allowed_characters = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range(0,9));

// We replace the valid characters with nothing - the result is: All     bad characters
$bad_characters = str_replace($allowed_characters, '', $string);

// We use the bad_characters to remove them from the original string
$sanitized_string = str_replace(str_split($bad_characters), '', $string);
echo $sanitized_string[0];
```

Comment: While this could work, I would need to make an endless list of `$special_character_list` =D

Comment: But if OP needs just the first symbol - he can check evey character and __break__ after found. And sometimes this will be faster than replacing symbols in the whole string.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson yea you're right. Check my second approach - this might do.

Comment: Super interesting. Any way to run a test to see if this is quicker than the regex one?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, this is about 4 times slower than your approach with the constant processing out of the benchmark loop.

Comment: The benchmark here is kinda weird. Sometimes it was 9x quicker, sometimes 3x slower. But we're talking on a very low level of processing time. So if you're not planning of doing this 24/7 without any pause with a lot of data - i am talking very big numbers 1 billion +, you'll be fine - if you really wanna avoid preg_match. Otherwise i will still recommend the preg_match over my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strpbrk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) to check if any non-special character exists in the string and get the substring out of it and print the first character. I have used `range` and `implode` to generate the chars list.

```
<?php

$string = ')(8234@#$ABCFG3478&* hello';
$chars = implode("",range('a','z')) . implode("",range('A','Z')) . implode("",range(0,9));

$str = strpbrk($string, $chars);

if($str !== false){
    echo $str[0];
}else{
    echo "No non-special character found";
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/nOQl7

Comment: How much quicker is this approach to the regex one I posted? Thanks.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, this is slightly slower than your approach, with the constant processing out of the benchmark loop. Benchmarking your approach at 0.015s and this at 0.021s for 100,000 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$string = ')(8234@#$ABCFG3478&* hello';

$length = strlen($string);
$firstLetter = null;

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
    if (ctype_alnum($string[$i])) {
        $firstLetter = $string[$i];
        break;
    }
}
```

This seems to be a little bit faster: https://3v4l.org/M08qg

(But I would prefer your preg_match approach!)

**EDIT:** And for strings with much more special chars at the beginning, it is much slower! https://3v4l.org/EFdLW
So the performance depends on the average length of special chars at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing hundreds of thousands of iterations of this technique, I don't think "speed" should factor into as a decision making criteria.

For me, I place a high importance on **directness** then **readability**.  For this reason, I probably wouldn't entertain a technique that generated arrays, incorporated a loop, or frankly, made more than one function call.  Regex isn't evil (I, for one, love it), so unless there is another single-function technique, I opt for regex every time.

That said, the only non-regex way (that isn't terribly convoluted) that I found is as @rid commented with `strcspn()`.

- `preg_match()` has the benefit of being more concise, arguably easier to read, and will not cause headaches if  your project needs to honor multi-byte characters in the future.
- `strcspn()` does not generate a temporary array/variable from which the correct value must be extracted, and is very likely to outperform any `preg_` call but not to a noticeable/valuable degree.

Notice that in my demo, the "character mask" seems to accept not more than one range of characters.  It would be handy if I could specify `A..Za..z0..9`, but I was unable to get that to work.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WQtRi))

```
$strings = [
    ')(8234@#$ABCFG3478&* hello', // mix
    '456456', // numeric
    'ghijkl', // alphabetic
    '!@#$%^&*(', // non-alphanumeric
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_export(
        [
            'string' => $string,
            'firstAlphaNumeric1' => preg_match('/[a-z0-9]/i', $string, $match) ? $match[0] : null,
            'firstAlphaNumeric2' => $string[strcspn($string, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')] ?? null,
            'firstAlphaNumeric3' => $string[strcspn($string, 'A..Zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')] ?? null,
        ]
    );
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'string' => ')(8234@#$ABCFG3478&* hello',
  'firstAlphaNumeric1' => '8',
  'firstAlphaNumeric2' => '8',
  'firstAlphaNumeric3' => '8',
)
array (
  'string' => '456456',
  'firstAlphaNumeric1' => '4',
  'firstAlphaNumeric2' => '4',
  'firstAlphaNumeric3' => '4',
)
array (
  'string' => 'ghijkl',
  'firstAlphaNumeric1' => 'g',
  'firstAlphaNumeric2' => 'g',
  'firstAlphaNumeric3' => 'g',
)
array (
  'string' => '!@#$%^&*(',
  'firstAlphaNumeric1' => NULL,
  'firstAlphaNumeric2' => NULL,
  'firstAlphaNumeric3' => NULL,
)
```

Ultimately, I'd go for `preg_match()` because I have used it thousands of times in my career as a php dev.  Conversely, I've probably used `strcspn()` a maximum of 1 time in my career (outside of playing around on Stack Overflow) -- so there is a lack of familiarity / intuitive-ness.